# Function doesn't do operations on dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R programming, so my question can appear naive.
I want to define all my functions of R in a single file, named functions.R, and call when I need them. I thought to use source().

That's my code:

main.R:

```
 library(gstat)
 library(lattice)
 library(rgdal)

 source("functions.R")
 source("script_import.R")
```

script_import.R:

```
source("functions.R")

#Here I import the dataset named "dati"
dati<-read.csv2("/home/eugen/Documenti/file_da_importare.csv", header = TRUE, skip=4, dec = ",")

colnames(dati)<-c("provider", "ente", "nome_stazione", "long", "lat", "quota", "periodo_dati", "anni_dati", "tm_01", "tm_02", "tm_03", "tm_04", "tm_05", "tm_06", "tm_07", "tm_08", "tm_09", "tm_10", "tm_11", "tm_12", "remove", "tn_01", "tn_02", "tn_03", "tn_04", "tn_05", "tn_06", "tn_07", "tn_08", "tn_09", "tn_10", "tn_11", "tn_12", "remove1", "tx_01", "tx_02", "tx_03", "tx_04", "tx_05", "tx_06", "tx_07", "tx_08", "tx_09", "tx_10", "tx_11", "tx_12", "stato", "note", "nazione")

#That's the function call with which I have problems
clean_main_ds()

#If I use this commands instead of the function all works well
#dati$remove<-NULL
#dati$remove1<-NULL
```

functions.R:

```
clean_main_ds<-function(){
  #I want to delete two columns
  dati$remove<-NULL
  dati$remove1<-NULL
  cat("I'm exiting the function")
  return(dati)
}
```

When compiling I don't receive any error, the function appears as declared in rstudio, is called by script_import.R, the cat() works well (so I imagine that there's no problem with the call), but the function doesn't delete the two columns. If I use the same commands ("dati$remove<-NULL") in script_import.R, instead of the function, all works well. 
Where's the error? How can I do to let my function operate on a dataset defined in another file?

Thank you very much for the help, 
Eugen

Ps: sorry for the errors in the language, I'm not english. I hope that the text is clear enough...

Comment: Using calls like `dati$remove<- NULL` only works if 'remove' is the actual name. If you wnat to do this properly read `?'['` and avoid the syntactic sugar of the `$` function. (This is also a highly duplicated question on SO.) Furthermore you didn't appear to assign the value of the function, so it just gets garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I thought that the function self modify the global dataset, I didn't think I needed to reassign the value. And yes, remove it was the name of the column to be removed. Really thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the assignment operator `<-` within a function, it only does an assignment within the function's own environment. That is, the function creates a copy of the object `dati`, and then assigns `NULL` to elements `remove` and `remove1` of `dati` *within the function's environment*.

Now when you use `return`, the function will return this modified copy of the original object `dati`. It will *not* modify the object `dati` in the global environment. If you do `str(clean_main_ds())`, you'll notice that that object is actually your data frame with the columns removed.

There's a couple of things you could do to get around this. First, you could specify your function using the assignment operator `<<-`, which will do assignment in the global environment instead of the function's own environment:

```
clean_main_ds<-function(){
      #I want to delete two columns
      dati$remove<<-NULL
      dati$remove1<<-NULL
      cat("I'm exiting the function")
      return(dati)
    }
```

(In fact, doing this, you don't even need the last line `return(dati)` in the function. By the time you get there your function has already done the modifications to your object in the global environment.)

Another option would be to just assign the value returned by your original function to the original data frame by
`dati <- clean_main_ds()`.

Finally, you could just remove the columns from your data frame directly, without writing a function for it, by using indexes.

```
dati <- dati[ , -which(colnames(dati) %in% c("remove", "remove1"))]
```

(You could do this directly by just specifying the column numbers of the columns to remove instead of the `which()` segment. That part just looks up the indexes of the columns whose name is `remove` or `remove1`.)